# View or edit internal Total Commander commands

Tags: total-commander

Is there a way to edit or view the code of internal TC commands?

There is a bunch of internal commands I can assign to my hotkeys (cm_CopySrcPathToClip, cm_CopyToClipboard, cm_LoadSelectionFromFile etc.).

But what if I need to change the way a command works? Is the code for the commands stored somwhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, but the main reason they're called "internal" is that handling of those internal commands is literally *part of totalcmd.exe itself*. So in order to change their behavior you would need to obtain Total Commander's source code, edit and recompile it.

Unfortunately, Total Commander is *not* open-source, so your only options are:

- see if its plugin system allows adding custom commands, and if so write a plugin;
- see if the same task can be done by running an *external* tool;
- contact the author with a feature request (or bug report);
- use reverse-engineering tools to patch the compiled .exe directly (a bit difficult and probably not very legal, considering WCMD's shareware status).

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! I don't really have a solid goal yet and I just wanted to play around with the TC scripting, understand what language is in use and how to create custom commands, etc.

Comment: The answer to which is that TC does not _have_ "scripting"; i.e. just because it offers a list of predefined tasks doesn't mean there's any sort of extensible language hiding behind them.